# Return after all promises resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, return, promise, es6-promise

Having a code sample below, I'd like to get baz variable returned from 'main' function after all promises resolved.

```
exports.foo = function(bar) {

    var baz;

    // some kind of promises are here forming array of promises p
    // some of promises may change the baz variable

    Promise.all(p).then(() => {
      // returning expression for main function is here
      // return baz here // does not work
    });

    // return baz //cannot be done because it would be earlier than all the async promises are resolved
}
```

Comment: foo() doesnt return anything. You have to return Promise.all.then and handle the promise in the caller method.

Comment: It'd be best if the promise chain resolved to `baz` and keep on working within the promise chain.

Comment: Something tells me this is only because of pseudocode writing, but it is *very* crucial: Is it actually `return Promise.all(p).then(() => {`? Without the `return`, it's always going to come back undefined.

Comment: One important thing is, you cannot return value synchronously from a function which does asynchronous activity

Comment: Just return a promise for `baz`! `return Promise.all(…).then(…);`

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promises resolve *after* main returns, so return a promise of baz instead:

```
exports.foo = function(bar) {
  var baz;
  return Promise.all(p).then(() => baz);
}

exports.foo(3).then(baz => console.log(baz)).catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Comment: ohhh gawd.. so simple but elegant. This whole javascript promise/async/wait is driving me a little crazy coming from the vanilla Java dev background.